# Cannot get authenticated user info, but can get address book from Google Contacts

Tags: java, oauth, google-api, google-contacts-api

I ran into an interesting case where it seems to indicate that the documentation for Google Contacts API is incorrect.

What I'm trying to do is getting the contact information of authenticated user who has already given permission to the app using this URL:

> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/contactId

The result of the call is always status 404. However, when I'm trying to get full address book, it seems to be working fine.

> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

Is it documented incorrect or I'm doing something wrong? It makes no sense that I can get the whole address book without being able to get contact information of the authenticated user.

The scope I'm using is:

> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds

Thanks,
Jack

---

Additional information. The API documentation shows the following:

```
public static ContactEntry retrieveContact(ContactsService myService) {
  ContactEntry contact =
      myService.getEntry(new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/contactId"),
          ContactEntry.class);
  // Do something with the contact.
  return contact;
}
```

This seems to mean that "contactId" keyword should used as part of URL. It just doesn't work for me.

---

To clarify this question. The goal is to get information on current authenticated user without having to go through workaround of fetching data multiple times. Even with the workaround of fetching all contact first, I didn't see any contactId of authenticated user coming back with it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to get. If you call https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full, then you are looking for all the contacts. Now, when you get back the contacts, you can request the data for a single contact by using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/{contactID} where {contactID} is the last part of the  field from the full contact list. It will look like http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{user email}/base/{contact id}.

So, if you get back the full contact list, a single contact will have an ID field that looks like: http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{user email}/base/{contact id}. If you take that last {contact ID} and append it to the end of the call (https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/{contactID} ), you will get back the contact information for just that contact.

Comment: This actually doesn't sound right at all. What I'm trying to do is get the contact information of the authenticated user only. If I have to make a call to get the contact list first, I wouldn't know the contact ID of the authenticated user anyway. I looked at it and it's definitely not the first one either. Even if there is a flag, I would then have to iterate through the whole list, which is very inefficient. If you take a look at the API, you will see that I'm supposed to use "contactId" as part of URL ( https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_a_single_contact).

Comment: Ahh. I understand now. In the response to the https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full call, you will see the root element of <feed>. Inside that is the element <id>. This has the email address of the authenticated user.

Comment: Hmmm...that's still an additional and unnecessary call to the backend. I guess if this's the way it has to be done, I will have to find an API that has the minimal logic to just get the contact ID. It seems that even profile API has the same issue.

Comment: Mark, I actually tried your suggestion and it still didn't work. I'm still getting a 404 when I append the id (email address). Then I did a quick check and found that contactId actually looks something like this "b78ea088ea9298". The only workaround I can think of right now is using profile API instead. I hope someone has a good suggestion for me.